# Understanding lift on a rotating cylinder (inviscid)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, aerodynamics, lift

From J.D Andersons [Aerodynamics book](https://www.amazon.in/Fundamentals-Aerodynamics-SI-John-Anderson/dp/0071289089), under the category of describing inviscid flow (over a rotating cylinder in this case), it states "...*the friction between the fluid and the surface of the cylinder tends to drag the fluid near the surface in the same direction as the rotational motion*"

It was at the end of the proof of lift for the inviscid flow, from what I've gathered the main reason of this lift is from the vortex elemental flow, causing circulation. However the description of "*friction between the fluid and surface*" seems odd given for inviscid flow there  **wouldn’t be** interaction with the surface and fluid. There is also the D'Alembert's paradox which was mentioned, yet would this not prove the no lift also?

So my question is, could there actually be lift in purely inviscid flow.